# JavaScript Regex to filter text between two characters

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group

I need to filter the text below from the string using `Regex JavaScript`:

Text: 'http://www.mywebsiteameW1234.com'

Should return only: **mywebsitename**

So between character dots and only lowercase letters:

**My attempt is only returning: mywebsitenameW1234 should remove the numbers:**

```
let text = 'http://www.mywebsitenameW1234.com'
console.log(text.match(/(?<=\.)(.*)(?=\.)/gm)[0])
```

I tried several ways to try to filter instead of (.*) putting something like ([a-z]+)
but always return null.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I add those filters in between groups look ahead/behind, etc..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one.

The `[a-z]*` expression ensures that it will only match lowercase letters after the first dot in the string.

```js
let text = 'http://www.mywebsitenameW1234.com'
console.log(text.match(/(?<=\.)[a-z]*/gm)[0])
```

Answer (score 4):

One expression, for instance, would be:

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([a-z]+).*
```

which is left bounded.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/8W3Cqi/1/)

---

Another one would be,

```
([a-z]+)[^a-z\r\n]*\.[a-z]{2,6}$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/MZigBb/1/)

which is right-bounded, and you could also double bound it, if that'd be necessary.

---

Or with lookarounds, one option would be,

```
[a-z]+(?=[^a-z\r\n]*\.[a-z]{2,6}$)
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/JmxRwG/1/)

```js
const regex = /https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([a-z]+).*/gm;
const str = `http://www.mywebsiteameW1234.com`;
const subst = `$1`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vaZZi8/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/vaZZi8/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]